# Display month of sale and number of sales done in that month sorted in descending order of sales

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

Display month of sale and number of sales done in that month sorted in descending order of sales.

I have used the extract function  to extract month from date but it gives month number not the full name of the month

```
select extract(month from sldate) as month, count(sid) as number_sale from sale 
 group by sldate  
order by sid desc
```

this is  the table

Sale Table

```
SALEID  SID SLDATE
1001    1   01-JAN-14
1002    5   02-JAN-14
1003    4   01-FEB-14
1004    1   01-MAR-14
1005    2   01-FEB-14
1006    1   01-JUN-15
```

Expected Result

```
MONTH        NUMBER_SALE
February    2
January         2
March           1
June            1
```

Comment: see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the original question tagged with MySql.
Instead of extracting just the month, you need to combine it with the year, because you don't want to mix sales of the same month in different years, so use `year_month` and then use [`monthname()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) to get the month's name:

```
select 
  monthname(concat(extract(year_month from sldate), '01')) as month, 
  count(sid) as number_sale 
from sale 
group by month
order by number_sale desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2XCgB1FN1Rids4bUW3Uig7/0).
Results:

```
| month    | number_sale |
| -------- | ----------- |
| February | 2           |
| January  | 2           |
| March    | 1           |
| June     | 1           |
```

Answer (score 0):

`select to_char(sldate,'Month') as Month,count(*) as number_sale from sale group by to_char(sldate,'Month') order by count(*) desc`
this is simplier solution

Comment: `to_char()` does not exist in mysql. How can this be the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SLDATE, 'Month') Month, COUNT(SALEID) NUMBER_SALE FROM Sale GROUP BY TO_CHAR(SLDATE, 'Month') ORDER BY NUMBER_SALE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select to_char(sldate,'Month') Month, 
 count(to_char(sldate,'Month')) NUMBER_SALE
 from sale  group by (to_char(sldate,'Month')) 
 order by  NUMBER_SALE desc
```

1. Displayed the month of sale and number of sales done in that month sorted in descending order of sales.

**OUTPUT**

```
MONTH   NUMBER_SALE
January     2
February    2
March       1
June        1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select to_char(sldate,'Month') as month,count(sid) as NUMBER_SALE from sale 
  group by to_char(sldate,'Month') 
order by NUMBER_SALE desc
```

Answer (score -2):

Check below Query

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SLDATE,'Month')"MONTH", COUNT(SID) AS NUMBER_SALE
FROM SALE
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(SLDATE,'Month')
ORDER BY COUNT(SID) DESC
```